# How to assign a nested list indices for later use

Tags: list-manipulation

In an attempt to calculate a summation dependent upon a nested list it appears that a simple use of `[[{n,k}]]` does not yield the desired result. For example with the script

```
M[n_, k_] := Table[Binomial[i + j - 2, i - 1], {i, n}, {j, k}]; 
T:= Join[{{1}}, Table[Abs[CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n, n], 
  x], x]], {n,1,10}]]
```

is needed to get the nested list. If `T=T[n_,k_]` is the desired label of the `Join[{{1}}, ...]` segment which list manipulation indicator is best for making `T[n_,k_]` functional enough to use in a summation?

A sample application would be

```
M[n_, k_] := Table[Binomial[i + j - 2, i - 1], {i, n}, {j, k}]; 
T:= Join[{{1}}, Table[Abs[CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n, n], 
  x], x]], {n,1,10}]][[{n,k}]]
Table[Sum[T[2*n, k], {k,0,n/2}], {n,0,10}]
```

but when implemented the result is

```
{{List, List}[0, 0], {{1}, List}[2, 0], {{1, 1}, List}[4, 0] + {{1, 1}, {1}} 
  [4, 1], {{1, 3, 1}, List}[6, 0] + {{1, 3, 1}, {1}}[6, 1], {{1, 9, 9, 1}, 
  List}[8, 0] + {{1, 9, 9, 1}, {1}}[8, 1] + {{1, 9, 9, 1}, {1, 1}}[8, 2], 
  {{1, 29, 72, 29, 1}, List}[10, 0] + {{1, 29, 72, 29, 1}, {1}}[10, 1] + 
  {{1, 29, 72, 29, 1}, {1, 1}}[10, 2]}
```

**Edit and answer:**
This issue is with trying to make a table of values in

```
T:= Join[{{1}}, Table[Abs[CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n, n], 
  x], x]], {n,1,10}]] .
```

By changing this to

```
T[n_, k_]:= If[n==0 && k==0, 1, Abs[Coefficient[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n,n],x],x]]];
```

then the issue is resolved and leads to

```
M[n_, k_]:= Table[Binomial[i+j-2, i-1], {i, n}, {j, k}];
T[n_, k_]:= If[n==0 && k==0, 1, Abs[Coefficient[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n,n],x],x]]];
Table[Sum[T[2*n, k], {k, 0, n/2}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

with the result:

```
{1, 3, 58, 702, 14121, 198591, 3825540, 56244564, 1046476305, 15719909355, 285386285826}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question - do you just want to be able to access individual elements in the 2D list `T`? If this is the case, does `T[[n,k]]` do what you want? (Using the definition of `T` from the first code block)

Comment: @LukasLang Asking questions in a rushed manor leaves for confusion. Yes, assigning a position of the data, say {n,k}, for later use in `T[n,k]` is what is being sought.

Comment: Why do you use `SetDelayed` in `T := [...]`? Why not just using `Set` like `T = [...]`. Otherwise `T` is recomputed each time you call it.

Comment: Maybe you also want to learn about memoization. I think `ClearAll[T];
T[n_, k_] := 
  T[n, k] = If[n == 0 && k == 0, 1, 
    Abs[Coefficient[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[n, n], x], x]]];` does the magic you want and prevents `T[n, k]` from being evaluated over and over again.